# inline-level elements vs phrase elements vs block level elements

Tags: html

I am new to Web programming, 
Can I please know what is the difference between inline level elements vs phrase elements ?
em and strong they are phrase elements ? but are they inline too, I don't quite get the difference,

Also if you could add what is significance of knowing blocklevel elements in relation to inline, phrase elements,

Thanks,

Comment: What's a phrase element?

Comment: @j08691 Phrase elements add structural information to text fragments that's what I know of them em, strong , cite and code etc are examples of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different HTML specifications and drafts use partly different terminology. Moreover, some of the concepts have CSS counterparts. Confusing these with each other can be really confusing, so let’s focus on the HTML 4.01 specification.

It has a section on [block-level and inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3), which is somewhat confusing. The fundamental distinction is formal and syntactic: some elements (e.g., `p`) are designated in the spec as block level, others are inline. Generally, you cannot put a block level element inside an inline element, but rules like this are really set in the syntax of element. The default formatting normally renders a block level element as a rectangle that occupies the available width, but this can be changed by a style sheet.

The distinction is supposed to be practical, helping people understand some rules easier. To some extent, it also has independent informational value. For example, the HTML specs do not specifically say that an `ul` element by default starts on a new line, and implies a line break after it too, and occupies the available width. This is more or less implied in designating it as block level element.

“[Phrase element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1)” is a term defined syntactically by enumerating some (inline) elements: EM, STRONG, DFN, CODE, SAMP, KBD, VAR, CITE, ABBR, and ACRONYM. The spec tries to describe this by saying that such elements “add structural information to text fragments”. This is meant to say that these elements say something about the meaning or role of their contents. For example, EM is said to mean emphasis (whatever that means). This is in opposite to inline elements like FONT and I, which indicate presentational features of text. But the “phrase level” concept is far from clear, and it has no special relevance in HTML.

Answer (score 4):

The term "phrase element" was last used in the HTML4.01 specification, section *9.2.1 Phrase elements*:

> Phrase elements add structural information to text fragments. The usual meanings of phrase elements are following [followed by a list of phrase elements] ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1)).

They are **rendered** as inline-level elements, they do not form new blocks of content. In HTML5 they are redefined as [*phrasing* elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing).

For block-elements have a look at the [CSS2.1 specification (section *9 Visual formatting model*)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html):

> Block-level elements are those elements of the source document that are formatted visually as blocks (e.g., paragraphs). The following values of the 'display' property make an element block-level: 'block', 'list-item', and 'table'.

So *phrase* or *phrasing* is more a semantical attribute, while *inline-level* or *block-level* is more a rendering attribute. Most phrasing elements are inline-level elements, most flow elements block-level elements.